# Impersonation okay local but not on server

Tags: ibm-mq, impersonation

I am having a problem with *I think* impersonation, but I could be mistaken.

I have an IBM XMS consumer, consuming data from a queue. Works fine. In order to be granted access to the queue the service needs to be running as specific user, for this I have implemented .Net impersonation. On all systems I am able to get the queue running, the problem occurs when there is a need to restart.

To test restart I have placed a simple **if(messages == 500) throw...** which triggers cancellation, disconnection and reconnection.

I installed the application as a Windows service to my local machine, it connects (using impersonation), reaches 500, throws, disconnects, reconnects and continues to process messages. However when I run the same code on our server it fails while trying to create a queue connection. Here is the error:

> 7765 [20] ERROR SIS (null) - Unable to connect to Websphere MQ
>   IBM.XMS.XMSException: CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the
>   call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection:
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
>   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId,
>   Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId,
>   Boolean firstModuleOnly)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId)
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Modules()    at
>   IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.TraceEnvironment()    at
>   IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.CreateCommonServices()    at
>   IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.TraceEnabled()    at IBM.WMQ.MQBase..ctor()
>   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.Phconn..ctor(NmqiEnvironment env)    at
>   IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiEnvironment.NewPhconn()    at
>   IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqConnection..ctor(NmqiEnvironment nmqiEnv, NmqiMQ
>   nmqiMQ, XmsPropertyContext connectProps)    at
>   IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Factories.WmqConnectionFactory.CreateV7ProviderConnection(XmsPropertyContext
>   connectionProps). During execution of the specified method an
>   exception was thrown by another component. See the linked exception
>   for more information.    at
>   IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Factories.WmqConnectionFactory.CreateProviderConnection(XmsPropertyContext
>   connectionProps)    at
>   IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection(String
>   userID, String password)    at
>   IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection()    at
>   Spin.TradingServices.DataAcquisition.Domain.DataProcessing.SIS.SISMQConnection.Connect(ImpersonationCredentials
>   impersonationCredentials)
>
> Linked Exception : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005):
>   Access is denied    at
>   System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32
>   access, Boolean throwIfExited)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId,
>   Boolean firstModuleOnly)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId)
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Modules()    at
>   IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.TraceEnvironment()    at
>   IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.CreateCommonServices()    at
>   IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.TraceEnabled()    at IBM.WMQ.MQBase..ctor()
>   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.Phconn..ctor(NmqiEnvironment env)    at
>   IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiEnvironment.NewPhconn()    at
>   IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqConnection..ctor(NmqiEnvironment nmqiEnv, NmqiMQ
>   nmqiMQ, XmsPropertyContext connectProps)    at
>   IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Factories.WmqConnectionFactory.CreateV7ProviderConnection(XmsPropertyContext
>   connectionProps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the user id being impersonated does not have enough permissions and not a problem with XMS.

Here is a link that may be of help to you.

[Access is denied at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314173/access-is-denied-at-system-diagnostics-process-startwithcreateprocessprocesssta)

and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/50a69129-5cc0-41f9-b83b-6b28a302a29d) also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on the IBM site there is a fix available for this error:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC90674

(please use the Wayback Machine https://archive.org/web/ if the URL is no longer available)

They also say that there is a local fix:

> Granting "Query process information and read process virtual
>   memory" rights to the impersonated user so that OpenProcess
>   succeeds.

Comment: I'd be interested to find out if anyone uses this and it works.